# Background color change in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to Highlight the row for 'Major group' and its 'subgroup' row in my report. where I have to change the background color of the row depending on the string value in the cell.

Ex: if the column has a value 'MG' in it, the cell should show a 'SomeColor, say Green' background color. I tried the following:

```
=IIF(Fields!ProductGroup.Value = "MG", "Green", "No Color")
```

tried

```
=Switch(Fields!ProductGroup.Value = "MG", "DarkViolet", Fields!ProductGroup.Value="SG","Gold")
```

Nothing is working for me. What am I missing?

Comment: Does your report have groupings?

Comment: Did you test iif and switch conditions if they work?

Comment: I had testing with IIF and switch. it didnt work .

Comment: Hi gbn, i have one row_group ? which displays the select query data

Comment: Can you post a simplified copy of your RDL?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SSRS 2008 or SSRS 2008 R2 Service Release 0 or earlier, No Color and Transparent are 8 digit hex codes ("#FFFFFFFF"), But Background Colors only support 6 digit Hex codes ("#FFFFFF"). The extra two bits are Transparency level and are not supported for Background Colors. You need to use Nothing instead to prevent warnings. I believe this has been fixed in SSRS 2012.

Comment: It is fixed in SSRS 2012

Comment: Unfortunately, 2012 and 2014 are with the same issue. Could you please show, how to add transparency level to the background image?

Answer (score 4):

Some Browsers cannot handle `"Transparency"` or `"No Color".`

It is best to add `"White"` as the background color. All browsers can handle white.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The problem is that `"No Color"` is not a defined color. Replace `"No Color"` with `"Transparent"`

Comment: I've migrated to SSRS 2016 and I'm having lots of warnings because Transparent is not a valid color. Replace Transparent with Nothing is the solution in my case. Or use White color.